# Ubuntu desktop Internet is not connecting in Ubuntu, connects in Windows

Tags: internet

I have Ubuntu desktop 16.04 and I cannot connect to the Internet via my wireless card on my motherboard. But I can connect to the Internet on my Windows 10 partition. I am not that savvy with Linux but why will my Ubuntu not connect to the Internet. I have an ultrabook so there is no Ethernet port.

https://pastebin.com/HzRb0S3m

Above is my network diagnostic page when run in Ubuntu.

Comment: What do you call "connecting to the internet"? is it about a wireless connection?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Pilot6: Probably since the computer has no Ethernet adapter (according to the question).

Comment: Question has been edited.